# Дописать числа в бинарный файл

Tags: c, binary-file

По заданию мне надо после каждого нечётного числа в бинарном файле написать целую часть его половины.
Мой список чисел в самом бинарном файле:
15
88
87
37
25
3
6
2
12
999
Сначала читает 15, 88, 87, а потом снова читает 88, 87, 88, 87..... и так до бесконечности.
Как с этими метками не возился, ничего не получается. Можете подсказать как надо правильно?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
 
int main()
{
    FILE* fb;
    char FileName[7] = "fb.dbl";
    int a;
 
    int err = fopen_s(&fb, FileName, "rb+");
    if (err != 0)
    {
        perror("Error opening the file ");
        _getch();
        return 1;
    }
 
    while (fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, fb) > 0)
    {
        if (a % 2 != 0)
        {
            int b = a / 2;
            fseek(fb, 0, SEEK_CUR);
            fwrite(&b, sizeof(b), 1, fb);
            //fseek(fb, sizeof(b), SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
 
    fclose(fb);
    return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: Что за непарные числа — неужто нечётные?

Comment: Да, имеется в виду нечётные

Comment: Вы какую-то ерунду делаете. Прочли. Если нечетное — *стали на начало*, записали, опять читаете *второе* число, опять, как нарветесь на нечетное — идете в начало, пишете... Издеваетесь, да? :) Кстати, а если идут одни только нечетные числа — куда писать собираетесь? Файл-то удвоится в размере! Так что пишите все в *новый* файл, а потом, по окончании — удалите старый, новый переименуйте в него...